# Whats the best way to update UI from aysnc task in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I don't know the very details of async task,
 I recently  used async task in my project to get some data from server side and update my UI according to the result,I implimented a progress dialog in the usual way and dismissid it in my onPostExicute method like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<StationSlots> result) {
    try {

    publishProgress(100);
    WizardStep4.retStationSlots =  result;      

        if (WizardStep4.this.dialog != null) {
                WizardStep4.this.dialog.dismiss();
          }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
     }
```

But I found some codes done the same thing but perfoming the action on a ui thread like this

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<StationSlots> result) {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
        try {
        publishProgress(100);
        WizardStep4.retStationSlots =  result;              
                if (WizardStep4.this.dialog != null) {
                    WizardStep4.this.dialog.dismiss();
                 }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

                }
            });
}
```

I like to know which one is the best method and what are the differences ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrong implementation approach of `AsyncTask` .

`protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<StationSlots> result)`

is Already running on **MainUiThread** so you don't have to write  `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` in `OnPostExecute()`.

Also `publishProgress();` is used to update UI from `doInBackground()` of AsyncTask as its running on a worker thread. And when you call `publishProgress();` form `doInBackground()` then execution comes on `onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)` which will also run on **MainUIThread** so you don't need any where `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` in AsyncTask. (except if you want to update UI from `doInBackground()` without calling `publishProgress();`)